# How to join list elements into strings?

Tags: python

I have a list here where I only need to input 10 letters or strings. I am having a problem separating the list.

```
print ("Please input letter: \n")
num_string = []
num = 10
for i in range (0,num):
    element = str(input(str(i + 1) + ". "))
    num_string.append(element)

string = ' '.join([str(item) for item in num_string])
print (string)
```

In my code, for example, I inputted a b c d e f g h i j since it is only 10 inputs. Instead of having an output like a b c d e f g h i j because I used the join method, I want to have a NewLine for every list. So I want it to be like

> a
>
> b
>
> c
>
> d
>
> e
>
> f
>
> g
>
> h
>
> i
>
> j

Comment: ``string_ = '\n'.join([str(item) for item in num_string])``, replace space with a new line

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there just instead of joining a whitespace, join a newline, also you don't need to convert each element to string because each element is a string already because `input` always returns a string (in Python3) (so this is redundant: `str(input())`, it is the exact same as: `input()`):

```py
string = '\n'.join(num_string)
```

Complete example (removed the redundant `str`):

```py
print("Please input letter: \n")
num_string = []
num = 10
# the 0 isn't necessary either but
# I guess for clarification it can stay
for i in range(0, num):
    element = input(str(i + 1) + ". ")
    num_string.append(element)

string = '\n'.join(num_string)
print(string)
```

Alternatively you can use this (instead of the last two lines in the above code example):

```py
print(*num_string, sep='\n')
```

And if you really want to shorten the code (it can be as short as 3 lines):

```py
print("Please input letter: \n")
num = 10
print('\n'.join(input(f'{i + 1}. ') for i in range(num)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print ("Please input letter: \n")
num_string = []
num = 10
for i in range (0,num):
    element = str(input(str(i + 1) + ". "))
    num_string.append(element)

string = '\n' .join([str(item) for item in num_string])
print (string)
```

Use '\n' , it is like a breakline in your output